# How do you locate a folder inside of Roaming using C#?

Tags: c#, directory, subdirectory, appdata, roaming

I'm trying to figure out a way to navigate to a sub folder in Roaming using C#. I know to access the folder I can use:

```
string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

What I'm trying to do is navigate to a folder inside of Roaming, but do not know how. I basically need to do something like this:

```
string insideroaming = string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData\FolderName);
```

Any way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string dir = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
    "FolderName"
);
```

It returns something similar to:

> C:\Users\<*UserName*>\AppData\Roaming\FolderName

If you need to get a file path inside the folder, you may try

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(
    dir,
    "File.txt"
);
```

or just

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
    "FolderName",
    "File.txt"
);
```

Comment: Let me make the question more clear, because I could see how someone could look at my question differently the way I wrote it. I have already combined the paths to create the folder, but what I need to do next is add a file into it. Would I use dir (Which refers to the string that I used for Path.Combine) to access this folder?

Comment: @Xceptionist You can use the same method or its overload to build the file path.

Comment: @Xceptionist If this answered your question, please mark it as the answer so it can help people who have a similar question in the future.

Answer (score -1):

```
string appDataFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string filePath = Path.Combine(appDataFolder + "\\SubfolderName\\" + "filename.txt");
```

Comment: It seems counterproductive (not to mention messy) to use a combination of `Path.Combine` and string concatenation - why not just use `Path.Combine` for the whole thing?